# Accelerator for Ctrl+left mouse button click

Tags: java, swing

I have an Action and need an accelerator for it. More exactly for <kbd>Ctrl+left</kbd> mouse button click I need the action to get executed. I tried with:

```
putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK, InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK));
```

But no luck...

**Later edit...**

I can achieve the functionality with a mouse listener but I need an accelerator for the Action in order to show up nicely when added to a popup similar to this image:

[image]

Comment: What are you calling `putValue` on and for what component?

Comment: I need the action to get executed for a JPanel component.

Comment: If you want the action to happen when you mouse click on the panel (regardless of `Ctrl`), then key bindings is not the way to go. You need a `MouseListener`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a `MouseListener` on your `JPanel` and then check if the CTRL key is pressed in the event. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


    text.setText("Mouse clicked");

    if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e) &&e.isControlDown()) {
        text.setText("left  + CTRL clicked");
    }

}
```

Comment: I have edited my question to better understand what I actually need. The action works just fine but I need an accelerator for it.